# positioning of elements in xaml

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, listpicker

I have 2 ListPicker's.
For example:

```
        <toolkit:ListPicker FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullItemTemplate}" ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkItemTemplate}"
            x:Name="lpkIcon">
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
        <toolkit:ListPicker  FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullItemTemplate}" ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkItemTemplate}"
            x:Name="lpkWhen">
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

This Listpickers are located near. When i am click on first listpicker it shows the menu, but its covered by the second listpicker.

I tried to disable the visibility of second listbox when i click on first, but i think everything can be done through the xaml.
sorry for really stupid question and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presuming you're talking about when the ListPicker is NOT in full mode (which opens in full screen).

How the two list pickers will interact visually will ultimately depend on the type of panel they're both contained in. So I can't give you a better answer unless I know which Panel you're using.

I use a lot of List Pickers in one of my apps [To Do Today](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone/to-do) and my best suggestion is to use a Stack Panel wrapped with a Scroll Viewer.